# MongoDB $project and $in in aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following structure:

```
{  
   "_id":"some_id",
   "tweets":[  
      {  
         "id":"1077633161922785281",
         "created_at":"Tue Dec 25 18:32:21 +0000 2018",
         "favorite_count":1905,
         "retweet_count":27,
         "media":[  

         ],
         "text":"Chillin",
         "avatar":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1062579676508381184/gDukIs20_normal.jpg",
         "name":"Chance Morris",
         "display_name":null,
         "user_id":"1087348778",
         "likedBy":[  
            "some-random-dude"
         ],
         "likes":1
      }
   ]
}
```

I would like to project that `likedBy` array to `liked: true/false` if the user's ID exists in the array.

```
  return db().collection('gamers').aggregate([
    {
      $project: {
        'tweets.id': 1,
        'tweets.likedBy': 0,
        "tweets.is_liked" : {
          $in: [ "some-random-dude", '$tweets.likedBy' ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]).toArray()
```

Even if the user's id is contained in the likedBy array, I still get `is_liked: false` no matter what

Any ideas of what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) since `tweets` is an array and `likedBy` is another, inner array, try:

```
db.gamers.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            tweets: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$tweets",
                    as: "tweet",
                    in: {
                        id: "$$tweet.id",
                        is_liked: { $in: [ "some-random-dude", { $ifNull: [ "$$tweet.likedBy", [] ] } ] }
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
    }
])
```

EDIT: you can use [$ifNull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/index.html) to avoid an error when there's no `likedBy` in `tweets`

Comment: Hmm, I get  `MongoError: $in requires an array as a second argument, found: missing`

Comment: Does it matter that I have 10 tweets, and only 1 of them has likedBy: [] array. The other ones do not even have an empty likedBy array ?

Comment: @DenkoMancheski yes, it matters, you can fix that using `$ifNull`, modified my answer

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm :)

Comment: is it possible to keep the same idea, but use $addFields instead of $projection without getting a repeated array of `id, is_liked` pair in every single object in `tweets`?

Comment: @DenkoMancheski sure, you can use `$addFields` to achieve the same result

Comment: Hmm, if I change $project to $addFields and `tweets` to `tweets.is_liked`, I get all the whole tweets array repeated in every tweet.. screenshot: http://prntscr.com/lzrwln

Comment: @DenkoMancheski I think you need to create another question and describe your query and expected result

Comment: I created one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53934300/mongodb-addfields-and-in-in-aggregate. Not sure if I explained it well tho