# MongoDB $addFields and $in in aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following structure:

```
{  
   "_id":"some_id",
   "tweets":[  
      {  
         "id":"1077633161922785281",
         "created_at":"Tue Dec 25 18:32:21 +0000 2018",
         "favorite_count":1905,
         "retweet_count":27,
         "media":[  

         ],
         "text":"Chillin",
         "avatar":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1062579676508381184/gDukIs20_normal.jpg",
         "name":"Chance Morris",
         "display_name":null,
         "user_id":"1087348778",
         "likedBy":[  
            "some-random-dude"
         ],
         "likes":1
      }
   ]
}
```

I would like to `$addFields` `is_liked` if `likedBy` array contains `user_id` and  `$project` :`likedBy: 0` to hide the array

```
 db().collection('gamers').aggregate([
{
  $project: {
    'tweets.likedBy': 0
  }
},
{
  $addFields: {
    'tweets.is_liked': {
      $map: {
        input: "$tweets",
        as: "tweet",
        in: {
          id: "$$tweet.id",
          text: "$$tweet.text",
          is_liked: { $in: [ "some-random-dude", { $ifNull: [ "$$tweet.likedBy", [] ] } ] }

        }
      }
    }
  }
}  ])
```

The issue is that the `$map` array is repeated in every item: screenshot: https://prnt.sc/lzrwln

Basically the end result would be replacing the `likedBy` array with `is_liked: true/false`, so I will not have to carry the array in FE just to check if the user liked or not

Answer (score 2):

You can use [$mergeObjects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/index.html) to combine existing tweet with `is_liked` field and then use [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/index.html) to exclude `likedBy` array from final result, try:

```
db.gamers.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            tweets: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$tweets",
                    as: "tweet",
                    in: {
                        $mergeObjects: [
                            "$$tweet",
                            { is_liked: { $in: [ "some-random-dude", { $ifNull: [ "$$tweet.likedBy", [] ] } ] } }
                        ]                            
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "tweets.likedBy": 0
        }
    }
])
```