# Mongodb : How to convert a field inside a nested array of object

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Is there any way to convert a field inside a nested array of object in a query ?

Here is a simple exemple :

My collection :

```
{ _id: 1, quizzes: [ { _id: 1, question: "bla bla 1"}, { _id: 2, question: "bla bla 2"}, ... ] },
{ _id: 2, quizzes: [ { _id: 1, question: "bla bla 1"}, ... ] }
```

Currently, my `_id` are `ObjectId`, I want to convert all of them including `quizzes._id` to `string`.

So here is the expected final result

```
{ _id: "1", quizzes: [ { _id: "1", question: "bla bla 1"}, { _id: "2", question: "bla bla 2"}, ... ] },
{ _id: "2", quizzes: [ { _id: "1", question: "bla bla 1"}, ... ] }
```

Here is what I got so far :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
        $addFields: {
            _id: { $toString: "$_id" }, // OK
            quizzes: { $map: { input: "$quizzes", in: { $toString: '$$this._id' }}}
])
```

But this is wrong, each quizze Object is fully transformed to a string, not just the id.

I am using Mongo 3.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return an object so instead of `in: { $toString: '$$this._id' }` it should be:

```
{ _id: { $toString: '$$this._id' }, question: "$$this.question" }
```

try:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            _id: { $toString: "$_id" },
            quizzes: { $map: { input: "$quizzes", in: { _id: { $toString: '$$this._id' }, question: "$$this.question" } }}
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/z6JPJwy-I9N)

Comment: hello mickl, thank you for your quick answer. Your solution works. But my real object "quizze" has a lot of fields. Moreover, more can be added in the futur. Is there a way to avoid listing all of them in my in: expression ?

Comment: @loonis you can use `$mergeObjects` like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53934300/mongodb-addfields-and-in-in-aggregate/53934351#53934351